# How do I get a client's IP address from behind a load balancer?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I am using TcpClient to listen on a port for requests.  When the requests come in from the client I want to know the client ip making the request.

I've tried:

```
Console.WriteLine(tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
var pi = networkStream.GetType().GetProperty("Socket", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var socketIp = ((Socket)pi.GetValue(networkStream, null)).RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(socketIp);
```

All of these addresses output 10.x.x.x addresses which are private addresses and are clearly not the address of **the clients off my network** making the requests.  What can I do to get the public ip of the clients making the requests?

**Edit:**
We are using an Amazon EC2 Load Balancer with tcp forwarding.  Is there a way to get the true client ip in this set up?

Comment: how can you be sure the addresses are "clearly" not those of the clients off your network.  Do you at least know the IP range your clients reside in?  Do they reside in your internal network, do they reside out in the public internet?

Comment: Because they all begin 10. - This indicates a private ip range not a public ip address.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like perhaps your server is behind a load balancer or router using [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).  In this case, the IP packet won't have the originating client's address, but the address of the NAT router.  Only the NAT router knows the sender's address (on an IP level).

Depending on whatever higher-level protocol you might be using on top of TCP, you may be able to get client identification from that, although it's much easier to spoof such information at higher levels, if that may be a concern.

If you need this data only for research purposes, your NAT device may keep a log.

If it's a requirement that you get the true originating IP packet in real time, you may have to have to reconfigure your router or have your server moved to the DMZ, but that's a whole nother ball of wax.  Talk to your network guys, as they would certainly know more about this than I (I'm not a network expert).

Comment: We are using an Amazon EC2 Load Balancer with tcp forwarding - any ideas on how I can get this to give me the requesting client ip?

Comment: You'll have to get in touch with Amazon on that.  It might be an add-on package for an additional fee.

Answer (score 106):

Does this work:

```
((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()
```

If the client is connecting to you via an internal network I am not sure you can get their public IP since the connection to get back to the client would not need that information.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the connection socket object of Socket class which you have used to accept the client.

```
connectionSocket.RemoteEndPoint.toString();
```

Answer (score -5):

```
AdresseIP = DirectCast(SocketClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address.ToString
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as @Kelsey answer, just in `vb`?

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer. If you just provide code (especially for more complex answers), people may not know how to use it.