# c# Ping a TCP Client from the server

Tags: c#, tcp

How can a `TcpClient` be pinged from a server in order to see its response time? I have a `TCPServer` that I have created with a `TCPClientManager` that I have also created. This simply adds a new `Client` with a .NET `TcpClient` property to a`List` whenever a client connects. How can I get the address of the `TcpClient` so that I can ping it using .NET `Ping` ?

```
public long PingClient(Client client)
{
    long pingTime = 0;
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();

    // The class Client has a property tcpClient of type TcpClient
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(Client.tcpClient...???);
    PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(address);

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        pingTime = reply.RoundtripTime;
    }

    return pingTime;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get client ip address using TcpClient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717381/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-using-tcpclient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want the `IPAddress` of the connected `TcpClient` which can be accomplished by accessing the underlaying socket (which is exposed through the `Client` property) and using it's `EndPoint` property.

You will have to cast it to an `IPEndPoint` in order to access it correctly.

In your case just use `((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address` which will return an `IPAddress`.

So you would have to change your example from:

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(Client.tcpClient...???);
```

to:

```
IPAddress address = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
```